# Ansible - Is there a way to change a Windows Server IP address using Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I want to use Ansible to setup a new domain controller. I have a script to clone a new server from a template, now how do I set the IP address of the Windows Server statically using Ansible?

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spent a good few hours finding the answer to the same question :) Hope below helps:

```
- name: Set up static IP address
  win_shell: "Get-NetIpAddress -InterfaceAlias 'Ethernet' | New-NetIpAddress -IpAddress 192.168.1.120 -PrefixLength 24 -DefaultGateway 192.168.1.1"
  async: 100 # Using "fire-and-forget" asynchronous execution for this task, otherwise it will always fail and timeout
  poll: 0

- name: Change ansible's ip address for each host
  set_fact:
    ansible_host: "192.168.1.120"

- name: Wait for the hosts network interface to come back up
  local_action:
    module: wait_for
    host: "{{ ansible_host }}"
    port: 5985
    delay: 10
    state: started
  register: wait_result

- name: Create a test folder to celebrate success
  win_file:
    path: C:\itworks
    state: directory
```

Comment: The win_shell command may need to be modified from `'Ethernet'` to `'Ethernet*'` depending on how your server is set up. This changed allowed ansible to find the only Ethernet interface and change it successfully on my Windows Server 2019 VM.

Answer (score -1):

I just simplify the previous snippet of code for me  :

```
[...]
- name: Set up static IP address
  win_shell: "Get-NetIpAddress -InterfaceAlias 'Ethernet*' | New-NetIpAddress -IpAddress 192.168.1.120 -PrefixLength 24 -DefaultGateway 192.168.1.1"
  async: 100 # Using "fire-and-forget" asynchronous execution for this task, otherwise it will always fail and timeout
  poll: 0

- name: Wait for the hosts network interface to come back up
  local_action:
    module: wait_for
    host: "{{ ansible_host }}"
    port: 5985
    delay: 10
    state: started
  register: wait_result
[...]
```

Credits to @fairgod

Comment: Can you clarify why you deleted that and why it will work? Thank you

Comment: I did not need to perform these tests :